# Dynamically created Knockout observable does not change value when a bound control (also dynamically created) is changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm working on an MVC Web application with ASP.NET and Knockout js (V3.5.1).
I'm struggling with Knockout observable not updated when an input value is change. Both of them are dynamically created in Javascript. The initial value set to the observable is not reflected on the input when the observable is created. I'm puzzled why the observable not catching the input's change.

Please find my code below for further demonstration. I really appreciate if there is any help.

**CustomViewModel.cs**

```
    public class CustomViewModel
    {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public int Prop { get; set; }
    }
```

**HTML with Razor**

```
@model CustomViewModel

<div id="inputContainer"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval", "/Scripts/ViewModels/CustomFormViewModel.js")
    <script>
        var vm = new CustomFormViewModel(@HtmlHelperExtensions.HtmlConvertToJson(Html, Model));

        vm.createInput = function (data) {
            return `@Html.Editor("Prop", new { @htmlAttributes = new { @id = "${data.Id}Prop", @data_bind = "value: ${data.Id}Prop" } })`;
        };
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>
}
```

**/Scripts/ViewModels/CustomFormViewModel.js** code

```
function CustomFormViewModel(self) {
      var self = this;

      var data = loadData();
      self[`${data.Id}Prop`] = ko.observable(data.Prop);

      var newInput = self.createInput(data);
      $("#inputContainer").append(newInput);
};
```

Comment: The reassignment of the argument "self" to var self, on the first line of CustomFormViewModel, means the data passed into the function in the anonymous script "var vm = new CustofmFormViewModel..." is ignored. I don't know if that's the cause of the problem, but it's a place to start.

Comment: agree to the comment above :9

Comment: Sorry man but... your models are wrong, your html creation is wrong, your javascript contexting is wrong, and its not gonna be an easy answer to incorporate all of those things in one answer....

Comment: Your js context assignment "this" is used wrong.
Your html creation is somewhat wrong. Dont append with jQuery elements. You should restruct your view and tie those components on boolean vm properties for example

Comment: @BillB Yes, you are correct. It should be 'entity' passed in from the view, not self, my mistake. Thank you for response. My problem is creating the input on the fly when knockout already applied bindings, as per MKougiouris.

Comment: @MKougiouris Thank you for your input. It's not elegant to create an HTML element this way. The tight knot here is that the application won't know how many input elements need to be created until the user chooses an option. I'm puzzled with that too.

Comment: @KatherineHa when you say the input needs to be created on the fly, what do you mean by that. Also don't try to mix knockout and razor. Expecting that they will interact together is inviting a world of hurt.  Razor is server side, knockout is client side. so by the time knockout is doing its thing, razor has finished rendering the html.

Answer (score 1):

I will only focus on the issue at hand- which is the input.

In general, since you are using knockoutJS you should refrain from using jQuery to append elements to the dom, instead you should change your View, so that it reflects what you are trying to achieve.

So you should have something like so:

```
<div data-bind="if: showThisInput">
    <input data-bind="value: myBindedObservable"
</div>
```

This way you control if the input should be rendered/shown, instead of appending it later on via jQuery.

When you call applyBindings you only bound to any html already existing on the view. Because you are injecting the input AFTER you have already bound the vm to the view, the engine does not know of the element since its not controlled by knockout, but rather added by you manually.

One way to solve this would be to actually call the razor inside the normally rendered view, so that when the applyBindings is executed, the input element exists on the dom

```
@Html.Editor("Prop", new { @htmlAttributes = new { @id = "${data.Id}Prop", @data_bind = "value: ${data.Id}Prop" } })
```

The only other option would be to clearBindings on the element and-rebind, which is also a bad practice for this use-case.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the important thing that I'm missing out. I ended up using this approach because the application doesn't know how many elements should be created before hand. It needs to listen to the user selection then create everything dynamically. Now I see that you won't recommend this bad practice. Is there other approach to overcome this?

Comment: Once you get the hang of it, knockout is pretty fast to work with. For you specific case, i would hold an array for items and on my view i would have an observableArray, at first initiialized with an empty array like so ko.observableArray([]).
Once the user clicks on an "selected this item" you would push the item's id/description on that new array.
On your view you would have a separate place to render your list of items from that array.
So a user cliicks a button -> the buttons method adds a new item on the array
 -> the view will render your section bound to that new array

Comment: And yes you can mix razor and knockout, but you need to remember how they mix. Razor is server side, so you can prepare your html in any way you want, inject javascript with razor, as you do, at the end of the day razor will produce a simple html/js page, which is then delivered to the client and onto which the client can simply applyBindings, this is also an option, depending on how the app is structured.
So you can have a razor part getting some data, iterating and making a list of inputs dynamically and then the client will applyBiindings normally on the finalized html result

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Binding a section (div) to an observableArray sounds good, I will try it. But I want the input to be inserted also bound to an observable. So that when it's changed, knockout can detect that. And the user selection is from the select list, if they choose 1st option -> create 2 input and 2 respective observables, 2nd option -> 5 input and 5 observables. Could it be possible? If there is a code example that would be so helpful.

Comment: You could have your items inside the observableArray to also contain a property of observableArray. Imagine an array of observables like so:
[{ Title: 'GroupId1', inputs: ko.observableArray( [] ) } , ... ]
On your select element, you attach a custom click handler, than on click will check what the selected item is, it will then lookup the observableArray over the Title to find the related detail object, and then it would push a new 'inputObject' in the inputs.
This in turn would allow you to have a nested div for the nested property "inputs" where you will just iterate and render

Comment: If you are working with components it would make "clearing up" the structure of things much easier, right now i can not provide a working sample on this :S

Comment: Your suggested approach sounds much neater, thank you. I will try it out.